# Unable to deploy SlingServlet in CQ

Tags: java, aem, servlet-3.0, sling

I'm trying to create a servlet in CQ to access some back-end services. Then from my page will make an AJAX call to get the response from servlet.

```java
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = false, label = "feedServlet")
@Service(Servlet.class)
@Properties(value = {
    @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = "POST"),
    @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.resourceTypes", value ="/bin/feedServlet/"),
    @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.selectors", value ="POST"),
    @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.extensions", value ="html")
})
/**
 * This servlet returns search results in json format.
 */
public class FeedServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2139716879248038562L;

    /*
     * Inject the service in to the servlet.
     */
    // @Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_UNARY, policy = ReferencePolicy.STATIC)
    // private SearchService searchService;

    // @Reference(cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_UNARY, policy = ReferencePolicy.STATIC)
    // private FeedGeneratorService feedService;

    /*
     * @Reference private SlingRepository repository;
     */

    /**
     * Bind repository.
     * 
     * @param repository the repository
     */
    /*
     * public void bindRepository(SlingRepository repository) { this.repository = repository; }
     */

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet#doPost(org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest,
     * org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse)
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServerException,
            IOException {

        String feed = "test test test";

        response.getWriter().write(feed);
    }
```

And from my page,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#button1").click(function(){
      alert(0);
      var formData = 'tcc=123';
      $.ajax({
            url : '/bin/feedServlet/',
            type: 'POST',
           data : formData,
         success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
         {
             alert("1 : "+data);
            // alert(eval(jqXHR));
            //data - response from server
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
      });
  });

});
```

But, while making the request I'm getting an error:

```
18.04.2014 00:25:51.185 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1397805951183] POST /bin/feedServlet/ HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation Unable to create resource named feedServlet in /bin
18.04.2014 00:25:51.185 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1397805951183] POST /bin/feedServlet/ HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation Exception during response processing. javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No child node definition for feedServlet found in node /bin
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.addNode(NodeImpl.java:1276)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.AddNodeOperation.perform(AddNodeOperation.java:111)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.AddNodeOperation.perform(AddNodeOperation.java:37)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.session.SessionState.perform(SessionState.java:216)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:91)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.addNodeWithUuid(NodeImpl.java:1814)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.addNode(NodeImpl.java:1766)
    at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.create(JcrResourceProvider.java:439)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.create(ResourceResolverImpl.java:1076)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.AbstractCreateOperation.deepGetOrCreateNode(AbstractCreateOperation.java:530)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.AbstractCreateOperation.processCreate(AbstractCreateOperation.java:104)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation.doRun(ModifyOperation.java:91)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.AbstractPostOperation.run(AbstractPostOperation.java:92)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.SlingPostServlet.doPost(SlingPostServlet.java:202)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:148)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:344)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:375)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:508)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:146)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:356)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:168)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:301)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:290)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:64)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:221)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.doFilter(CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:127)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:206)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:96)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:79)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:42)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:127)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:263)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:179)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:88)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:47)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:33)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:48)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:39)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletRuntimeEnvironment.service(ServletRuntimeEnvironment.java:250)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.doFilter(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:321)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:340)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.RequestDispatcherImpl.service(RequestDispatcherImpl.java:383)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.ServletHandlerImpl.process(ServletHandlerImpl.java:335)
    at com.day.j2ee.servletengine.HttpListener$Worker.run(HttpListener.java:644)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: no matching child node definition found for {}feedServlet
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.nodetype.EffectiveNodeType.getApplicableChildNodeDef(EffectiveNodeType.java:744)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.getApplicableChildNodeDefinition(NodeImpl.java:817)
    at org.apache.



jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.addNode(NodeImpl.java:1274)
    ... 98 more
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have got your properties wrong. Kindly refer to the [sling docs](http://sling.apache.org/documentation/the-sling-engine/servlets.html) to know what each property that you have set does.

The property `sling.servlet.paths` should be used instead of sling.servlet.resourceTypes to provide the path under which the servlet is accessible as a Resource.

Thus for your requirement, the following annotations would suffice.

`sling.servlet.methods` - For the request methods supported by the servlet.

`sling.servlet.paths` - For the request path that is handled by this servlet.

```
@Component(immediate = true, metatype = false, label = "feedServlet")
@Service(Servlet.class)
@Properties(value = {
    @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = "POST"),
    @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value ="/bin/feedServlet"))
})
public class FeedServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2139716879248038562L;

    @Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServerException,
            IOException {

        String feed = "test test test";

        response.getWriter().write(feed);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have made the changes in my Sling Servlet. But Even after the changes, its giving me the same error.`code` 18.04.2014 11:45:09.026 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1397846709020] POST /bin/feedServlet/ HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation Exception during response processing. javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No child node definition for feedServlet found in node /bin
Caused by: javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: no matching child node definition found for {}feedServlet

Comment: Your path property shouldn't contain the trailing slash. Change /bin/feedServlet/ to /bin/feedServlet

Comment: Thanks have done the necessary corrections. But Still I'm not able to make it work.

1. In the error log I'm geting the same error which says,

`code`
    18.04.2014 21:36:43.198 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1397882203193] POST /bin/feedServlet HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation Exception during response processing. javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No child node definition for feedServlet found in node /bin
     at org.apache.jackrabbit.core.NodeImpl.addNode(NodeImpl.java:1276)`code`

Comment: Did you check your /system/console/components whether your servlet s registered there and is active??

Comment: Hi, my OSGi Bundle which contains the servlet is in active state. It is deployed with out any error in error log. I have around 4 servlets in my bundle (for testing purpose), but none of them is visible in the  /system/console/components. I'm using maven to build the bundle from eclipse.

Comment: Well then there is some issue.Your servlets not listed down in the components indicates something else is going wrong somewhere. Are you sure your classes have compiled without any error? Did you try creating the same bundle directly in CQ5 without using maven and check if it is working ok?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Think I found the issue. My OSGi bundle does not have the "serviceComponents.xml" file in the OSGI-INF folder. As I said earlier I'm using cqblueprints structure and eclipse. No idea why this is not generating.

Comment: Good. Try to figure out why it is behaving so :) And then check if it is working fine.