# Sling Servlet as a Service in CQ5 (OSGi Bundle)

Tags: servlets, osgi, aem, sling

We trying to create a osgi backend service for CQ5. We are using the cqblueprints archetype with eclipse as the dev environment. And we are able to deploy it to CQ using the console. In the CQ Web console we can view the details of the bundle as

```
com.acme.wcm.cq - acme-corporate-servicescom.acme.wcm.cq.acme-corporate-services
Symbolic Name   com.acme.wcm.cq.acme-corporate-services
Version 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Bundle Location inputstream:acme-corporate-services-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
Last Modification   Fri Apr 18 12:30:34 PDT 2014
Description Bundle containing the backend services for acme CQ
Start Level 20
Bundle Classpath    .,OSGI-INF/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar,OSGI-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.3.jar,OSGI-INF/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar,OSGI-INF/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.rome-1.0_3.jar,OSGI-INF/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jdom-2.0.2_1.jar,OSGI-INF/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxen-1.1.6_1.jar,OSGI-INF/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j-1.6.1_5.jar,OSGI-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
Exported Packages   com.acme.wcm.cq.exception,version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
com.acme.wcm.cq.feed,version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
com.acme.wcm.cq.feed.util,version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
com.acme.wcm.cq.filter,version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
com.acme.wcm.cq.osgi,version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
com.acme.wcm.cq.search,version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
com.acme.wcm.cq.servlet,version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
com.acme.wcm.cq.servlet.model,version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
com.acme.wcm.cq.util,version=1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Imported Packages   com.day.cq.search,version=0.0.0 from com.day.cq.cq-search (209)
com.day.cq.search.result,version=0.0.0 from com.day.cq.cq-search (209)
com.day.cq.wcm.api,version=1.0.0 from com.day.cq.wcm.cq-wcm-api (288)
javax.jcr,version=2.0.0 from org.apache.sling.jcr.jcr-wrapper (76)
javax.jcr,version=1.1.0 from org.apache.sling.jcr.jcr-wrapper (76)
javax.servlet,    ble,version=0.0.0.1_007_JavaSE from org.apache.felix.framework (0)
javax.swing.tree,version=0.0.0.1_007_JavaSE from org.apache.felix.framework (0)
javax.xml.bind,version=2.1.0 from org.apache.felix.framework (0)
javax.xml.namespace,version=0.0.0.fragment_xml from org.apache.felix.framework (0)
javax.xml.stream,version=1.0.0 from org.apache.felix.framework (0)
javax.xml.stream.events,version=1.0.0 from org.apache.felix.framework (0)
javax.xml.stream.util,version=1.0.0 from org.apache.felix.framework (0)
javax.xml.validation,version=0.0.0.fragment_xml from org.apache.felix.framework (0)
org.apache.sling.api,version=2.2.0 from org.apache.sling.api (123)
org.apache.sling.api.request,version=2.3.0 from org.apache.sling.api (123)
org.apache.sling.api.resource,version=2.3.2 from org.apache.sling.api (123)
org.apache.sling.api.servlets,version=2.1.0 from org.apache.sling.api (123)
org.osgi.framework,version=1.6.0 from org.apache.felix.framework (0)
org.slf4j,version=1.6.4 from slf4j.api (14)
Manifest Headers    Bnd-LastModified: 1397849403046
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_45
Built-By: jsunny
Bundle-Activator: com.acme.wcm.cq.osgi.Activator
Bundle-ClassPath: ., OSGI-INF/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar, OSGI-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.3.jar, OSGI-INF/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar, OSGI-INF/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.rome-1.0_3.jar, OSGI-INF/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jdom-2.0.2_1.jar, OSGI-INF/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxen-1.1.6_1.jar, OSGI-INF/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j-1.6.1_5.jar, OSGI-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar
Bundle-Description: Bundle containing the backend services for acme CQ
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: com.acme.wcm.cq - acme-corporate-services
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.acme.wcm.cq.acme-corporate-services
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Embed-Dependency: *; scope=compile|runtime
Embed-Directory: OSGI-INF/lib
Embed-Transitive: true
Embedded-Artifacts: OSGI-INF/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar; g="com.googlecode.json-simple"; a="json-simple"; v="1.1", OSGI-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.3.jar; g="commons-lang"; a="commons-lang"; v="2.3", OSGI-INF/lib/gson-2.2.4.jar; g="com.google.code.gson"; a="gson"; v="2.2.4", OSGI-INF/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.rome-1.0_3.jar; g="org.apache.servicemix.bundles"; a="org.apache.servicemix.bundles.rome"; v="1.0_3", OSGI-INF/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jdom-2.0.2_1.jar; g="org.apache.servicemix.bundles"; a="org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jdom"; v="2.0.2_1", OSGI-INF/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxen-1.1.6_1.jar; g="org.apache.servicemix.bundles"; a="org.apache.servicemix.bundles.jaxen"; v="1.1.6_1", OSGI-INF/lib/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j-1.6.1_5.jar; g="org.apache.servicemix.bundles"; a="org.apache.servicemix.bundles.dom4j"; v="1.6.1_5", OSGI-INF/lib/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar; g="xml-apis"; a="xml-apis"; v="1.0.b2"
Export-Package: com.acme.wcm.cq.exception; version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT", com.acme.wcm.cq.feed; uses:="javax.jcr, com.day.cq.search.result, org.apache.sling.api.resource"; version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT", com.acme.wcm.cq.feed.util; uses:="javax.jcr, com.day.cq.search.result, org.apache.sling.api.resource"; version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT", com.acme.wcm.cq.filter; uses:="javax.servlet, org.apache.sling.api.request, org.apache.sling.api, org.slf4j"; version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT", com.acme.wcm.cq.osgi; uses:="org.osgi.framework"; version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT", com.acme.wcm.cq.search; uses:="javax.jcr, com.day.cq.search.result, org.apache.sling.api"; version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT", com.acme.wcm.cq.servlet; uses:="org.apache.sling.api.servlets, javax.servlet, org.apache.sling.api, org.slf4j, javax.jcr, com.acme.wcm.cq.search, com.day.cq.search.result, com.acme.wcm.cq.exception, com.acme.wcm.cq.servlet.model"; version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT", com.acme.wcm.cq.servlet.model; version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT", com.acme.wcm.cq.util; uses:="javax.jcr, com.day.cq.search.result, org.apache.sling.api, com.day.cq.search, org.apache.sling.api.resource, com.day.cq.wcm.api, org.apache.sling.api.servlets, javax.servlet"; version="1.0.0.SNAPSHOT"
Import-Package: com.acme.wcm.cq.search, com.day.cq.search, com.day.cq.search.result, com.day.cq.wcm.api, com.sun.msv.datatype; resolution:=optional, com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd; resolution:=optional, javax.jcr; version="[2.0, 3)", javax.servlet, javax.swing.table, javax.swing.tree, javax.xml.bind, javax.xml.namespace, javax.xml.stream, javax.xml.stream.events, javax.xml.stream.util, javax.xml.validation, nu.xom; resolution:=optional, org.apache.sling.api; version="[2.2, 3)", org.apache.sling.api.request; version="[2.2, 3)", org.apache.sling.api.resource; version="[2.1, 3)", org.apache.sling.api.servlets; version="[2.1, 3)", org.gjt.xpp; resolution:=optional, org.jdom; resolution:=optional, org.jdom.input; resolution:=optional, org.jdom.output; resolution:=optional, org.osgi.framework; version="[1.4, 2)", org.relaxng.datatype; resolution:=optional, org.slf4j; version="[1.6, 2)", org.xmlpull.v1; resolution:=optional
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Tool: Bnd-1.50.0
```

But, if I search in the Services menu (in the Felix Console) nothing I could find which I have created.

Is this normal? To verify this I have crated a Simple servelet

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
 org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Component(immediate = true, metatype = false)
@Service(value = javax.servlet.Servlet.class)
@Properties(value = { @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = { "GET" }),
        @Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = { "/path/to/my/servlet", "/apps/path/to/my/servlet" }) })
public class AbsoluteUrlServlet extends SlingSafeMethodsServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -1920460619265757059L;
   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AbsoluteUrlServlet.class);

   @Override
   protected void doGet(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
      logger.debug("AbsoluteUrlServlet::doGet()");
      response.setContentType("text/plain");
      response.getOutputStream().print("Hello AbsoluteUrlServlet World!");
   }
}
```

But, when I request the servlet from browser,

```
    http://localhost:4502/apps/path/to/my/servlet
```

I'm getting the following error.
    No resource found

```
Cannot serve request to /apps/path/to/my/servlet in /libs/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.jsp
Request Progress:

      0 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) TIMER_START{Request Processing}
      0 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) COMMENT timer_end format is {<elapsed msec>,<timer name>} <optional message>
      0 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) LOG Method=GET, PathInfo=/apps/path/to/my/servlet
      0 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) TIMER_START{ResourceResolution}
      0 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) TIMER_END{0,ResourceResolution} URI=/apps/path/to/my/servlet resolves to Resource=NonExistingResource, path=/apps/path/to/my/servlet
      1 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) LOG Resource Path Info: SlingRequestPathInfo: path='/apps/path/to/my/servlet', selectorString='null', extension='null', suffix='null'
      1 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) TIMER_START{ServletResolution}
      1 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) TIMER_START{resolveServlet(NonExistingResource, path=/apps/path/to/my/servlet)}
      1 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) LOG {0}: no servlet found
      1 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) TIMER_END{0,resolveServlet(NonExistingResource, path=/apps/path/to/my/servlet)} Using servlet org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
      1 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) TIMER_END{0,ServletResolution} URI=/apps/path/to/my/servlet handled by Servlet=org.apache.sling.servlets.get.DefaultGetServlet
      1 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) LOG Applying Requestfilters
      1 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter
      1 (2014-04-18 12:33:58) LOG Calling filter: org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter
```

Please provide some pointers to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally able to find the reason.

I missed the `maven-scr-plugin` in my POM.xml due to which the serviceComponents.xml was missing in my bundle.(Please see [My previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149751/unable-to-deploy-slingservlet-in-cq))

Comment: Kindly include in your answer how you were able to generate the serviceComponents.xml. This may help others who might be facing the same problem.

Comment: Sure, I was missing "maven-scr-plugin" in my POM.