# CQ5 QueryBuilder Reference in Sling Servlet

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

I am declaring a sling servlet like so

```
@Component(metatype = false)
@Service(Servlet.class)
@Properties({
        @Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value = "/bin/foo/bar"),
        @Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = "POST") })
public class FooBarServlet extends SlingAllMethodsServlet {
    ...
}
```

I override doPost like so

```
@Override
    protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    ...
}
```

And I am able to post from a client. Great!

I throw in the following

```
@Reference
private QueryBuilder queryBuilder;
```

as per the documentation, a reference to query builder should be injected. But it does not seem to. In the log I see this error

```
bindQueryBuilder cannot be found (java.lang.VerifyError: ...
```

And when I try to post to the servlet I get this

```
javax.jcr.RepositoryException: org.apache.sling.api.resource.PersistenceException: Resource at '/bin/foo/bar' is not modifiable.
```

And in the OSGi console I see my bundle is installed, and this is what it has to say about my servlet

```
Service ID 3075 Types: javax.servlet.Servlet
Service PID: com.myproject.FooBarServlet
Component Name: com.myproject.FooBarServlet
Component ID: 5526
Vendor: Adobe
```

Any suggestions as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had been using [this](http://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/using-query-builder-api1.html) tutorial as a reference.
I came across [this](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-service-component-runtime.html) about the Felix Service Component Runtime (SCR)

and so I implemented the following

```
protected void activate(ComponentContext context) {
    LOGGER.info("activating {}", this.getClass().getName());
}

protected void unbindQueryBuilder(QueryBuilder queryBuilder) {
    this.queryBuilder = null;
}

protected void bindQueryBuilder(QueryBuilder queryBuilder) {
    this.queryBuilder = queryBuilder;
}
```

and it worked! So upon closer investigation I learned that these bind/unbind methods are actually supposed to be generated by the maven-scr-plugin, of which I have version 1.6.0

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>scr</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Private service properties for all services. -->
                            <properties>
                                <service.vendor>Adobe</service.vendor>
                            </properties>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

and for the annotations I have 1.4.0

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```

so although I am not sure why the bind/unbind methods are not getting generated, I know that they should be, so I generate them manually.

**Update**
I tried to update the maven-scr-plugin to version 1.20.0, which yielded the following error during mvn build

```
[ERROR] Project depends on org.apache.felix:org.apache.felix.scr.annotations:jar:1.4.0:provided
[ERROR] Minimum required version is 1.9.0
```

so... I updated the org.apache.felix.scr.annotations to 1.9.0. And it works! My bind/unbind accessors are generated and all is great. However, I am concerned and do not know if I should use version 1.9.0 of org.apache.felix.scr.annotations because I am marking it as `provided` in the maven dependency and when I look at the OSGi bundles installed on the cq instance I see the following

```
Apache Felix Declarative Services (org.apache.felix.scr) : Version 1.6.3.R1409029
```

Comment: Try using more recent versions of the [plugin](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/maven-scr-plugin/1.20.0) and [annotations](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.felix/org.apache.felix.scr.annotations/1.9.8). Methods should be indeed created automatically.

Comment: @TomekRękawek, I updated the dependencies and made updates above.

Comment: Guys, do you found the cause of the problem?

Comment: Somewhat. The maven-scr-plugin is not generating the bind/unbind accessors. To workaround, you can create them manually. Otherwise update the plugin and annotation dependency versions. Its all noted above.

Answer (score -4):

For the dependency injection to work, you should declare the member variable as public.

Try changing it to

```
@Reference
public QueryBuilder queryBuilder;
```

Comment: I disagree, you should never declare members public. For servlets you need to set it to "private transient".

Comment: I tried that, it did not work. On top of which it is not the way it is written in the documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Are you putting @Reference thing inside your doPost() method?