# posting data to Custom servlet in AEM6

Tags: servlets, aem, sling

I'm trying to create a servlet in CQ. Then from my page will make an AJAX call posting data to Custom servlet in AEM6 to get the response from servlet.
My servlet class is below

```
package Sample; 
        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.PrintWriter;
        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.URL;
        import java.rmi.ServerException;
        import java.util.Dictionary;         
        import java.util.Enumeration;        
        import javax.servlet.Filter;
        import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
        import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
        import javax.servlet.ServletException;
        import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;

        import org.apache.sling.api.adapter.Adaptable;
        import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
        import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;

        import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component;
        import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Properties;
        import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property;
        import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
        import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Service;
        import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.sling.SlingServlet;
        import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletRequest;
        import org.apache.sling.api.SlingHttpServletResponse;
        import org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet;
        import org.apache.sling.commons.osgi.OsgiUtil;
        import org.apache.sling.jcr.api.SlingRepository;
        import org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Reference;
        import org.osgi.service.component.ComponentContext;
        import org.slf4j.Logger;
        import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

        import javax.jcr.Session;
        import javax.jcr.Node; 

        import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

        import java.util.UUID;

        @Component(immediate = true, metatype = false, label = "HelloFormServlet")
        @Service(PollController.class)
        @Properties(value = {
            @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.methods", value = "POST"),
            @org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Property(name = "sling.servlet.paths", value ="/bin/HelloFormServlet")
        })

        /*@SlingServlet(paths="/bin/HelloForm", methods = "POST", metatype=true)*/
        public class PollController extends org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet {
             private static final long serialVersionUID = 2598426539166789515L;
             Logger log=LoggerFactory.getLogger(PollController.class);  
           /*  @Reference
             private SlingRepository repository;



             public void bindRepository(SlingRepository repository) {
                    this.repository = repository; 
                    }*/

             @Override
             protected void doPost(SlingHttpServletRequest request, SlingHttpServletResponse response) throws ServerException, IOException {

              try
              {
                  Enumeration paramNames = request.getParameterNames();

                while (paramNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                    log.info("getting values from jsp");
                }
                 /*//Get the submitted form data that is sent from the
                      //CQ web page  
                  String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                  String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
                  String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");
                  String address = request.getParameter("address");
                  String cat = request.getParameter("cat");
                  String state = request.getParameter("state");
                  String details = request.getParameter("details");
                  String date = request.getParameter("date"); 
                  String city = request.getParameter("city"); 

                  //Encode the submitted form data to JSON
                  JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
                  obj.put("id",id);
                  obj.put("firstname",firstName);
                  obj.put("lastname",lastName);
                  obj.put("address",address);
                  obj.put("cat",cat);
                  obj.put("state",state);
                  obj.put("details",details);
                  obj.put("date",date);
                  obj.put("city",city);

                     //Get the JSON formatted data    
                  String jsonData = obj.toJSONString();

                     //Return the JSON formatted data
                 response.getWriter().write(jsonData);
              */}
              catch(Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              } String feed = "This is some text from an external ASP file";
              response.getWriter().write(feed);
              log.info("passing off jsp");
            }
        }
```

**My JSP**

```
<%@include file="/libs/foundation/global.jsp"%>
    <%
    %><%@page session="false" %><%
    %><%
        // TODO add you code here
    %>
    <%@page import="com.kicker.disolutions.*"%>
    <%@ page import="java.util.*"%>
    <%@ page import="java.io.*;"%>
    <%@page session="false"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <cq:includeClientLib categories="jquerysamples" />
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>

    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script>

         $(document).ready(function() {
             alert("READY");            
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var failure = function(err) {
                 alert("Unable to retrive data "+err);
       };
       alert("in submit");

        var claimId = 2; 


        //Use JQuery AJAX request to post data to a Sling Servlet
        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',    
             url:'/bin/HelloFormServlet',
             data:'id='+ claimId,
             error:failure,
             success: function(msg){
                 alert(msg);

    $("#piechart").html(msg);
             }
         });
      });

    }); 
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div>r u satisfied?</div><br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans" value="yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans" value="no">NO<br>
    <div>r u satisfied?</div><br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans1" value="yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans1" value="no">NO<br>
    <div>r u satisfied?</div><br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans2" value="yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans2" value="no">NO<br>
    <div>r u satisfied?</div><br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans3" value="yes">Yes<br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans3" value="no">NO<br>
    <div>r u satisfied?</div><br>
    <input type="radio" name="ans4" value="yes">Yes<br> 
    <input type="radio" name="ans4" value="no">NO<br>
    <input id= "submit" type="submit" value="Submit" /><br>
        <div id="piechart" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

After execution my error is below

```
29.08.2015 00:53:18.386 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1440789798381] POST /bin/HelloFormServlet HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation Unable to create resource named HelloFormServlet in /bin
29.08.2015 00:53:18.387 *ERROR* [0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 [1440789798381] POST /bin/HelloFormServlet HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation Exception during response processing.
javax.jcr.nodetype.ConstraintViolationException: No default node type available for /bin/HelloFormServlet
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.util.TreeUtil.addChild(TreeUtil.java:185)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.NodeDelegate.addChild(NodeDelegate.java:692)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$5.perform(NodeImpl.java:286)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl$5.perform(NodeImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.delegate.SessionDelegate.perform(SessionDelegate.java:308)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.ItemImpl.perform(ItemImpl.java:113)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.addNode(NodeImpl.java:253)
    at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.session.NodeImpl.addNode(NodeImpl.java:238)
    at org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.helper.jcr.JcrResourceProvider.create(JcrResourceProvider.java:437)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.tree.ResourceProviderEntry.create(ResourceProviderEntry.java:479)
    at org.apache.sling.resourceresolver.impl.ResourceResolverImpl.create(ResourceResolverImpl.java:1053)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.AbstractCreateOperation.deepGetOrCreateNode(AbstractCreateOperation.java:578)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.AbstractCreateOperation.processCreate(AbstractCreateOperation.java:105)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.operations.ModifyOperation.doRun(ModifyOperation.java:91)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.AbstractPostOperation.run(AbstractPostOperation.java:92)
    at org.apache.sling.servlets.post.impl.SlingPostServlet.doPost(SlingPostServlet.java:200)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:148)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:344)
    at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:375)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:511)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:146)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:357)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:166)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:284)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
    at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:124)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.security.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:133)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:349)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:64)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:251)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.kicker.disolutions.impl.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.doFilter(CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:77)
    at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.cq.dam.s7imaging.impl.auth.MemoryTokenAuthHandler.doFilter(MemoryTokenAuthHandler.java:156)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:81)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:153)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:205)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:339)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:300)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:298)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
    at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
```

Please help.. tried [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149751/unable-to-deploy-slingservlet-in-cq) but didn't help

Comment: Is your servlet registered successfully. Check in `/system/console` if your servlet is registered and started. Also check in the `/system/console/jcrresolver` if the path `/bin/HelloFormServlet` is resolving to your servlet.

Comment: Servlet got registered successfully but not active.

Answer (score 0):

Basically changing @Service(PollController.class) to @Service(Servlet.class) worked for me.. i was able to post data after that.. (but the exact code of Enum is not working so had to remove while loop).
Thanks for looking into this  @rakhi4110

Comment: How did I miss that. Yes, `@Service` defines which service interfaces are provided by the component and in this case it should be the `Servlet.class` or should have been left blank. I would suggest, you add additional information to your answer so that people coming here might get more information.

Comment: You could drop the Service annotation and use SlingServlet. It does the same trick as the Service / Component combo.

Comment: @rakhi4110 i think i have provided all the info. wat more information u need? let me know